# Installing PyObjC in 10.9.5 fails

Tags: python, pyobjc

I'm having a hard time installing PyObjC in mavericks. I read other discussions here too and used many different resources and still I get same error when I try to import. for example:

```
from AppKit import NSObject
```

gives me this in console:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/bin/python /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pyobjc_framework_Cocoa-3.1b1-py2.7-macosx-10.9-intel.egg/AppKit/__init__.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pyobjc_framework_Cocoa-3.1b1-py2.7-macosx-10.9-intel.egg/AppKit/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    import Foundation
  File "Foundation/__init__.pyc", line 9, in <module>
  File "CoreFoundation/__init__.pyc", line 11, in <module>
  File "CoreFoundation/_inlines.pyc", line 14, in <module>
  File "CoreFoundation/_inlines.pyc", line 13, in __load
ImportError: 'CoreFoundation/_inlines.so' not found
```

What are your suggestions? Should I just delete all the modules and reinstall them. Has anyone been successful with the library in 10.9?
ps: I'm using Xcode 6.2

Thanks

Comment: How exactly did you install it?

Comment: I went to https://pythonhosted.org/pyobjc/install.html and used Manual Installation method.

Comment: I just tried in a virtualenv (on 10.10, but I have used PyObjC on Mavericks too), which works okay for me. You have to be careful not to mix the system Python and the Homebrew-installed Python.

Comment: I have both Homebrew and system Python. Should I uninstall brewed one?

Comment: Check out [`this`](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/share/doc/homebrew/Homebrew-and-Python.md#site-packages-and-the-pythonpath), perhaps it's fixable by adjusting `$PYTHONPATH` so it'll look in the Homebrew-based `site-packages` directory first (it's now looking in the system directory, `/Library/Python/2.7/...`). However, PyObjC is installed by default on Mavericks for the system Python, so it may be easier to just use that (depends on your requirements).